# Data lost in AWS EC2 after reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, elastic-beanstalk

After rebooting an EC2 Instance under Elastic Beanstalk environment I have lost most of the website related data which was stored in webroot. Webroot is showing a different version of datas which are almost a year back. I have lost most of the later added virtualhost related datas. But all the server configuration related files which I have updated a couple of days back are intact. No issues for them. Also there is no snapshot of that time is ever taken. How could something like this ever happen. Please help me to recover my data.

Comment: Was your data on an EBS volume or an ephemeral volume? Neither loses data after a reboot, but ephemeral loses data after a stop / start. I assume from your question it was on an EBS volume. If it's not there, and you have no snapshot, I'm sorry to say but the data is gone. This isn't something that happens in AWS, so the most likely cause is accidental user error. It's also possible your server was compromised. AWS gives you all the tools you need to secure your account and back up your server, but you need to use those tools.

Comment: It's a basic t2.micro instance and was using EBS volumes. I have rebooted similar instances before also. But this kind of a partial loss is for the first time. How can I lose a files only in a particular directory and not on other system directories on just a reboot?

Comment: I can't think of any way that could happen that could be caused by AWS. If the volume was damaged AWS would report that in the console and refuse to boot. If this is important data you could raise a support case with AWS, but you'd have to pay for support.